# Не могу запустить rasa init

Tags: python, cmd

Я не могу запустить rasa. Выдаёт что "rasa" не является внутренней или внешней командой исполняемой программой. Я перепробовал все: скачивал нужные версии, запускал через виртуальную среду, запускал просто через консоль, добавил пути в path.

Версия python - 3.9.0

Answer (score 0):

**UPD**

Проверил по версиям python, официально поддерживаются версии от 3.7 до 3.8.
Установка описанная ниже проверена на 3.8.

С доки

> Install Rasa Open Source using pip (requires Python 3.7, or 3.8).

Вы запускаете так сказать с общего котла. Для Windows на странице [документации](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation/) с первых строк пишут: "используйте виртуальное окружение". [Здесь](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/installation/)

Для windows

1. В папке где будет проект, открываете терминал и пишете

```
py -m venv venv
```

Должна в папке с проектом появиться папка `venv`

2. Далее команда в `cmd` выглядит так

```
env\Sctipts\activate
```

После этой команды в начале пути, отображаемого в термианале, будет видно `(venv)`. Это говорит о том, что вы в вирт пространстве и можете сюда устаноить `rasa`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Устанавливаете `rasa` в виртуальное окружение

```
pip install rasa
```

4. И только теперь `rasa init`

Все дальнейшие действия только через виртуальное пространство. Для windows НЕ используйте следующие команды (если сами ничего не переназначали): `python`, `python3`, `pip3`

Comment: Спасибо, у меня все получилось